# Getting exceptions on inserting into couchdb

Tags: java, json, exception, gwt, couchdb

I'm trying to insert data into couchdb but landed up to these exceptions
Here is the logs.

```html
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String org.rz.client.GreetingService.rr() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["error"] is not a JSONObject.
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:415)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["error"] is not a JSONObject.
 at net.sf.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:2163)
 at com.fourspaces.couchdb.CouchResponse.<init>(CouchResponse.java:90)
 at com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session.http(Session.java:365)
 at com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session.get(Session.java:325)
 at com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session.getDatabase(Session.java:183)
 at org.rz.server.GreetingServiceImpl.rr(GreetingServiceImpl.java:21)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
 ... 31 more
[ERROR] 500 - POST /rz/greet (127.0.0.1) 57 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
      DNT: 1
      Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8
      X-GWT-Permutation: 98267CD3F923780B0E51298DEFE71EBA
      X-GWT-Module-Base: http://127.0.0.1:8888/rz/
      Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/Rz.html
      Content-Length: 108
      Connection: keep-alive
   Response headers
      Content-Type: text/plain
```

fjjkbk hkj jk kjhkb h ghj j jhvjg ch vg jhvbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbt ygy gy yu gygggggugihngdlh d jgdfj hgdhgd hjd ghd dhdkjfhgdg hg sg df gf dgj fdkjg kdg d ghkd gkdh kgdghf gdfjkgkdkgd kg fkg kdkgkdf gdf g dfgjkdgd gj dgdkgkdh djd gdk gkfg kdkfkgdk gdk gkfghdkf gkdf ghdkfgkd fhg fkg fd ghdfk gd  ghfkgkfdgkf ghk

#### GreetingServiceImpl.java

http://pastebin.com/yZvQGLz7

Answer (score 0):

Hum, you're requesting from `Host: 127.0.0.1:8888` wich is not your database port according to your source code. You might also want to try this [example](https://code.google.com/archive/p/couchdb4j/wikis/Example.wiki)  to see if your setup is wrong or if it's your code.

Comment: It is requesting from 127.0.0.1:8888 bcoz of GWT web apps.Also I followed your link but no progress.